# ng-repeat order by number only positive value

Tags: angularjs

I have a list I want to sort based on a number. This number can be negative or positive. My idea is that the order of lowest to highest, but the number must be positive, negative automatically hidden. But I want to add an option, such as a selector that says only positive or All. If you select all showing both negative and positive but negative to the last. Whereas if I select only positive, show positive from lowest to highest. It could do this?

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="torneo in torneos | orderObjectBy:'dias'" item="item" class="item item-icon-right" ng-click="verTorneo(torneo.torneo_id)">
            {{torneo.torneo_nombre}} {{torneo.dias}}
            <i class="icon ion-ios-arrow-right"></i>
</ion-item>

app.filter('orderObjectBy', function(){
return function(input, attribute) {
if (!angular.isObject(input)) return input;

var array = [];
for(var objectKey in input) {
    array.push(input[objectKey]);
}

array.sort(function(a, b){
    a = parseInt(a[attribute]);
    b = parseInt(b[attribute]);
    return a - b;
});
return array;
}
})
```

This function directs me the numbers from lowest to highest, but have not been able to pull negative last. The order is as follows:

```
-3
-1
 2
10
```

What I want is

```
 2
10
-1
-3
```

Comment: Sorry, I update @thepio

Comment: Can you please create fiddle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you tried

```
array.sort(function(a, b){
    a = parseInt(a[attribute]);
    b = parseInt(b[attribute]);
    var A2 = (a < 0) ? 1 : 0;
    var B2 = (b < 0) ? 1 : 0;
    return (A2 == B2) ? a - b : A2 - B2;
});
```

Comment: Where the sort defined? the controller?

Comment: its better to share fiddle to understand it better

Comment: Question, I have such an arrangement: 1, -45, -10, 20, 10. The right order would be 1, 10, 20, -10, -45, however sample 1, 10, 20, -45, -10

Comment: uses Math.abs at comparator: return (A2 == B2) ? Math.abs(a) - Math.abs(b) : A2 - B2;

Answer (score 1):

try a sort defining the category "order" to define who comes before:

```
array.sort(function(a, b){
    a = parseInt(a[attribute]);
    b = parseInt(b[attribute]);
    var categoryA = (a < 0) 1 : 0;
    var categoryB = (b < 0) 1 : 0;
    return (categoryA == categoryB) ? a - b : categoryA - categoryB;
});
```

Comment: that array is my torneos??

Comment: My question is, where I define that .Sort

Answer (score 1):

If you want to solve this 'The angular way' you should delegate the formatting of output data to **filters**.

```
<ion-item
    ng-repeat="torneo in torneos | yourCustomFilter"
    ng-if="torneo.torneo_nombre > 0 || showNegatives"
    item="item"
    class="item item-icon-right"
    ng-click="verTorneo(torneo.torneo_id)">
            {{torneo.torneo_nombre}} {{torneo.dias}}
            <i class="icon ion-ios-arrow-right"></i>
</ion-item>
```

Then use a sorting algorithm in the filter, provided by other answers on this question. This way the sorting will be called automatically when the list updates and to show the negative numbers you only have to set `showNegatives` to true.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a filter which excepts a boolean that symbols if the negative value should show or not

```
app.filter("sortNegFilter", function() {
  return function(array, showNegative) {
    if(!showNegative){
        array = $filter("filter")(array, function(val){
            return val.torneo_nombre < 0;
        });
    }
    return $filter('orderBy')(array, 'torneo_nombre');
  };
});
```

Then bind the bool to your view, showNeg will be true when checked

```
<label><input type="checkbox" ng-checked="showNeg"> Show negative numbers </label>
<ion-item ng-repeat="torneo in torneos | sortNegFilter:showNeg" item="item" class="item item-icon-right" ng-click="verTorneo(torneo.torneo_id)">
    {{torneo.torneo_nombre}} {{torneo.dias}}
    <i class="icon ion-ios-arrow-right"></i>
</ion-item>
```